# Unsigned function to return digits using any numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm working on an exercise where I have to program an unsigned 
    function in C++  --- The function has returned the number of digits 
    in num and must work on any number.

```
The issue  --- when I do unsigned num is greater than 10 digits, it still 
shows 10 as the answer.  what am I doing wrong?


unsigned numDigits(unsigned num)  
{
if (num == 0)
return 0; 
return 1 + numDigits(num / 10); 
return (num);
}

int main()
{
unsigned num = 12345678901;
cout << "Number of Digits: " << numDigits(num);
}
```

Comment: Likely has to do with how big `unsigned` is: can it feasibly store more than 10 numbers? Likely not if it's 32-bits, since that would be 2^32, which just so happens to be 10 numbers

Comment: If it should work on "any" number, does it need to work on numbers bigger, even, than the long long solutions below? Words like "any" can be very expensive in computer software design.

Comment: You should have got a warning from the compiler that 12345678901 would not fit into unsigned int. "New" warnings are always worth reading, even if you decide in the end you have to live with them.

Answer (score 2):

unsigned size is:

```
0 to 65,535 or 
0 to 4,294,967,295 (10 digits)
```

So change your funtion into:

```
unsigned numDigits(long long unsigned num)
```

A cheat solution to your problem is also:

```
std::string dig = std::to_string(num);
std::cout << dig.size();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 unsigned getNumDigits(long long unsigned num)
 {
      if (num < 9 )
          return 1;
       return 1 + getNumDigits(num / 10 );
 }
```

@ram , thx for pointing out.
Max guaranteed unsigned value is 65535 . Accomodating values more than this will need a bigger (value accomodating) type. Max unsigned value is possible with long long unsigned . A value 0 also mean 1 digit hence comparison against 9 .